# Set Google Account on Server side without showing dialog for account selection

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

This is code from which I get GA data but it is always ask in browser for account selection. How to define default account in PHP script.

What I missing?

This is equal to index.php in GA documentation but I use Symfony framework and decided to change this route

```
/**
 * @Route("/get-google-analytics-data")
 */
public function getGoogleAnalyticsData () {
    $ga = $this->get('google_analytics_service');

    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);


    // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
    // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        // Set the access token on the client.
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

        // Create an authorized analytics service object.
        $analytics = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

        // Call the Analytics Reporting API V4.
        $response = $ga->getReport($analytics);

        // Print the response.
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($ga->printResults($response));

    } else {
        $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

        return $this->redirect($redirect_uri);
    }
```

This is equal to oauth2callback.php in GA documentation.

```
}
/**
 * @Route("/oauth2callback", name="gaOA2callback")
 */
public function gaOA2callback () {
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ .'/client_secrets.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . '/oauth2callback');
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
        if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

        return $this->redirect($auth_url);
    } else {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/get-google-analytics-data';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

        return $this->redirect($redirect_uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this was a bad idea. I had use wrong way of communicate with GA API.

```
function initializeAnalytics()
    {
        // Use the developers console and download your service account
        // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
        // change the key file location if necessary.
        $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

        // Create and configure a new client object.
        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
        $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
        $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics']);
        $analytics = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

        return $analytics;
    }
```

You can see .json file included in function. This file you can download from Google console Dashboard from your **OAuth 2.0 client IDs**
.

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=&authuser=1

If you do not have those you will ned to create a new one.

> Most important thing, **enter a valid VIEW_ID**, if you do not do that you
>   will get permission denied error and probably you will look for
>   solution on other places.

About permission, user of this API is not your email. it is service email, zou will  find it in .json file. And also you will need to set roles for that service email. For basic use view permissions will be just fine.

At end, to get data you can do that with function like this.

**$VIEW_ID = "123625914"; // **view ID is look like this**, you will find bunch of those vieew on GA Reporting Dashboard for your project.**

```
function getReport($analytics, $nameSystem) {

    // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
    $VIEW_ID = "123625914"; 

    // Create the DateRange object.
    $dateRange = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange->setStartDate("4000daysAgo");
    $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

    $today = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $today->setStartDate("today");
    $today->setEndDate("today");

    // Create the Metrics object.
    $views = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $views->setExpression("ga:pageviews");
    $views->setAlias("views");

    $user = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $user->setExpression("ga:users");
    $user->setAlias("user");

    $country = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $country->setName("ga:country");

    $continent = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $continent->setName("ga:continent");

    $event = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $event->setName("ga:eventLabel");
    $event->setName("ga:eventCategory");

    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    $request = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
    $request->setDateRanges([$dateRange, $today]);
    $request->setMetrics(array($views, $user));
    $request->setDimensions(array($event));
    $request->setFiltersExpression('ga:eventCategory==' . $nameSystem);

    $request1 = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request1->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
    $request1->setDateRanges([$dateRange, $today]);
    $request1->setMetrics(array($user));
    $request1->setDimensions(array($continent, $event));
    $request->setFiltersExpression('ga:eventCategory==' . $nameSystem);

    $request2 = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request2->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
    $request2->setDateRanges([$dateRange, $today]);
    $request2->setMetrics(array($user));
    $request2->setDimensions(array($event));
    $request2->setFiltersExpression('ga:eventCategory==' . $nameSystem);


    $body = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests( array( $request, $request1, $request2) );
    return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```